# Ignore filter on range aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Scenario: I'm searching for cars, and my first search happens without any filtering. 
I have two range aggregations:

- Price: *-5000, 5000-10000, 10000-*
- Seats: 2-*, 4-*, 5-*, 7-*, 9-* (I want to see how many cars have at least, say, 5 seats)

I also and several aggregations on boolean terms, e.g.:

- Aircon
- Natural gas

If I apply the filtering for aircon everything's good:

```
"aggregations": {
    "price_ranges" : {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "to": 5000,
                "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
                "from": 5000,
                "to": 10000,
                "doc_count": 4
            },
            {
                "from": 10000,
                "doc_count": 4
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But let's say that in the main query I apply a price filter, between 5000 and 10000. Now the other values are (correctly) zeroed, as they only apply to the docs retrieved.

```
"aggregations": {
    "price_ranges" : {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "to": 50,
                "doc_count": 0
            },
            {
                "from": 50,
                "to": 100,
                "doc_count": 4
            },
            {
                "from": 100,
                "doc_count": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is there a way to still have the totals as the first example (2, 4, 4) even if I'm filtering on price, without building/executing a second query?
2. Even making multiple queries, I'd have to make a distinct call with *all* filters except price to get all cars price ranges as in question 1, and a second one with *all* filters except seats (i.e. including price) to show those values as required. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I think you are looking for a post filter http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_post_filter.html#_post_filter

Comment: Can't: "The nature of the post_filter means it runs after the query, so any performance benefit of filtering (such as caches) is lost completely."